# Could not start vsixinstaller.exe, the VSIX installer process failed with exit code 1006

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, postsharp, vsix

When I am trying to install PostSharp 4.3.21 for Visual Studio 2013, error message is showing on screen as "could not start vsixinstaller.exe. The VSIX installer process failed with exit code 1006".

For it's solution I have tried to run it with Administrator but not find any success. Also I have installed PostSharp-4.0.42.vsix but not any success.

[image: Error_Screen]

Comment: I have got same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got solution of it as after **Updating VS 2013 with new updates**, Post-Sharp successfully installed.